# Docker compose linux volume - permission acess denied

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

Below is the Dockerfile for linux images. I get file path access denied error in Ubuntu VM
[image: Docker voulume permission denied]

```
environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/abc/https/localhost.pfx
    volumes:
      - ./devops/https/localhost.pfx:/abc/https/localhost.pfx:ro
```

The path in the image and dockerfile was the same at that time. Attempted to run on ubuntu. ubuntu user is added to docker group.
Docker file content is provided for reference.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY . App/
WORKDIR /App

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Production"
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:44123;"
ENV ABC_WORKDIR /App
ENV ABC_FILE_STORE /abc/source

EXPOSE 44123

RUN mkdir -p $ABC_FILE_STORE
RUN mkdir -p /abc/https

RUN chown abcuser /abc/https
RUN chown abcuser $ABC_FILE_STORE
RUN chown abcuser /App
USER abcuser


VOLUME /abc/https
VOLUME $ABC_FILE_STORE

WORKDIR $ABC_FILE_STORE
# sanity check: try to write a file
RUN echo "Hello from ABC" > hello.txt

WORKDIR $ABC_WORKDIR

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ABCService.dll"]
```

1. Should all the volume paths used by app, need to be mentioned and change the permission in Dockerfile
2. Should a docker file need to create a user and use it in dockerfile.
3. Above seems, both windows and linux need separate dockerfile for image creation

Comment: Hi, can you check in your container if the /https/localhost.pfx exists and who is the owner.

Comment: You seem to have included an image file in place of the error message; can you [edit] the question to fix this?  What code are you running that produces the error?  The `VOLUME` directives in your Dockerfile are probably unnecessary and may be causing problems (I expect the file `/abc/source/hello.txt` will not exist, for example).  If this is related to a volume mount, how are you starting the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze, Thanks. `RUN echo "Hello from ABC" > hello.txt` this line is executing, I have commented Volume directives. I am able to up and run the application on port 80. To run asp dot net I have to supply cert file via volumes in docker-compose file; then get the exception